# How to extract a JSON object within a dictionary in an Excel column using Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have an Excel file with one of the columns as JSON array. I want to extract the value of "category", "classification" and "count" from the object against the particular "sid".

Below is the input:

| SID | Summary |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | [{'tid': {'category': 'Furniture', 'classification': 'Table'}, 'Count': 5}, {'tid': {'category': 'Household', 'classification': 'Kitchenware'}, 'Count': 2}] |
| 102 | [{'tid': { 'category': 'Furniture', 'classification': 'Chair'}, 'Count': 7}] |

The expected output is :
[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

I had a similar issue with another script, used the below code, and it worked:

```py
import ast
    
df["Summary"] = df["Summary"].apply(
    lambda x: ",".join(y["name"] for y in ast.literal_eval(x))
)
```

`name` is the column name that was extracted using this code.
But it's not working for this code, since this is a dict inside the object instead of string.

Answer (score 0):

With following dataframe that you get by importing your Excel file:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "SID": [101, 102],
        "Summary": [
            [
                {
                    "tid": {"category": "Furniture", "classification": "Table"},
                    "Count": 5,
                },
                {
                    "tid": {"category": "Household", "classification": "Kitchenware"},
                    "Count": 2,
                },
            ],
            [{"tid": {"category": "Furniture", "classification": "Chair"}, "Count": 7}],
        ],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
new_df = (
    pd.json_normalize(
        df.explode("Summary").apply(
            lambda x: {
                **{"SID": x["SID"]},
                **x["Summary"]["tid"],
                **{"Count": x["Summary"]["Count"]},
            },
            axis=1,
        )
    )
    .groupby("SID")
    .agg(list)
    .applymap(lambda x: ", ".join([str(i) for i in x]))
    .reset_index()
)
```

```py
print(new_df)
# Output
   SID              category      classification count
0  101  Furniture, Household  Table, Kitchenware  5, 2
1  102             Furniture               Chair     7
```